# Using a simple pager within Drupal 7 (PagerDefault, db_select)

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am attempting to create a simple pager within Drupal 7 on `page.tpl.php` within my theme.
The aim of the pager is to show 5 'courses' per page, with a pager at the bottom.

After scrounging around online, this is the best I could get, which shows the first 5 items, and no pager:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit(5);
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->condition('type', 'course');
$result = $query->execute();
$output = NULL;
foreach($result as $row) {
    $output .= $row->nid.': '.$row->title.'<br />';
}
$output .= theme('pager');
echo $output;
```

Could anyone assist in how to correctly pull through a pager? Some answers mention to include `pager_default_initialize` but apparently this is not required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue I had by specifying the element, element 0 was already in use (hence it not working) changing to element 1 fixed it, I just changed

`$output .= theme('pager');`

to

`$output .= theme('pager', array('element' => 1));`

It seems that pager ID 0 was used by Views, by enabling the Archive block.

Answer (score 2):

For rendering pager with some query, you need call `$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(5);` before execute it.